# SQL Server view : assign historic employee department from an audit table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-view

I'm creating a SQL Server view. I have employee data from a time management system with clock in and out per day laid out in a table like the below, this is only an example, there are 100's of employee records.

```
DATE           USERID    CLOCK
--------------------------------
2020-02-25      1234    08:00:00
2020-02-25      1234    17:00:00
```

There is a Department and CostCode table but that only holds the current Department and CostCode, nothing historic. There is an audit table laid out like the below, the CHANGEDATE is in datetime format and also records the time the change was made.

```
CHANGEDATE          USERID  CHANGETYPE  NEWVALUE
-------------------------------------------
2019-01-01 hh:mm:ss 1234    DEPARTMENT  Warehouse
2019-01-01 hh:mm:ss 1234    DEPARTMENT  Stores
2019-05-01 hh:mm:ss 1234    COSTCODE    Store1
2020-02-25 hh:mm:ss 1234    DEPARTMENT  Shipping
2020-02-25 hh:mm:ss 1234    COSTCODE    Dock1
```

What I need to be able to do is assign the department and cost code of the time to the clock in/out data, like the below so I can see the department and cost code they were assigned to at the date of the clock. Using the above every clock employee 1234 has from between 01/05/2019 and 25/02/2020 gets assigned department = Stores and cost code = Store1, every clock before on and after 25/02/2020 is department = Shipping and cost code = Dock1, etc.

```
DATE       USERID     CLOCK    DEPARTMENT   COSTCODE
-----------------------------------------------------
2020-02-24  1234    09:00:00    Stores      Store1
2020-02-24  1234    18:00:00    Stores      Store1
2020-02-25  1234    08:00:00    Shipping    Dock1
2020-02-25  1234    17:00:00    Shipping    Dock1
```

Can anyone assist? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would build an intermediate View or CTE with a clean history for each attribute with begin and end date, then join that with your clock data using a range condition on the date:

```
WITH changes_periods AS (
  SELECT
    c1.USERID,
    c1.CHANGETYPE AS ATTR_TYPE,
    c1.NEWVALUE AS ATTR_VALUE,
    c1.CHANGEDATE AS VALID_FROM,
    COALESCE(MIN(c2.CHANGEDATE), '20990101') AS VALID_BEFORE
  FROM changes c1
    LEFT JOIN changes c2 ON c1.USERID=c2.USERID AND c1.CHANGETYPE=c2.CHANGETYPE AND c1.CHANGEDATE<c2.CHANGEDATE
  GROUP BY c1.USERID,c1.CHANGETYPE, c1.NEWVALUE, c1.CHANGEDATE
)
SELECT
  c.DATE,
  c.USERID,
  c.CLOCK,
  dep.ATTR_VALUE as DEPARTMENT,
  cc.ATTR_VALUE as COSTCODE
FROM clockdata c
  LEFT JOIN changes_periods dep ON
    c.USERID=dep.USERID
    and dep.ATTR_TYPE='DEPARTMENT'
    and c.DATE>=dep.VALID_FROM and c.DATE<dep.VALID_BEFORE
  LEFT JOIN changes_periods cc ON
    c.USERID=cc.USERID
    and cc.ATTR_TYPE='COSTCODE'
    and c.DATE>=cc.VALID_FROM and c.DATE<cc.VALID_BEFORE
```